# How to prevent initial white flash when showing a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I use a `UIWebView` to show an "About" screen by displaying a bundled HTML file. My app's view hierarchy is: `UITabBarController` / `UIViewController` / `UIWebView`.

The problem is that the HTML page has a dark background, and the very first time the tab is tapped, a white background is visible briefly before the web view is displayed. I tried setting the background color of the `UIWebView`, but that doesn't solve the problem. The problem occurs whether I load the content in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: you can hide the `UIWebView` until webview is not finish loading, and set it unhidden in `webViewDidFinishLoading`

Comment: I think I actually need to do the opposite: I.e., show it immediately, without delay, so that the white background is never visible.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Swift:

```
webView.isOpaque = false
webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Objective-C:

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked. By the way, would you know how to "pre-load" the content when the app starts? I'm attempting to do it from the app delegate and the tab bar, but not having luck.

Comment: I found the solution: sending -view to a UIView will cause it to pre-load correctly.

Answer (score 11):

// load index.html

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
self.webview.delegate = self;

self.webview.alpha = 0; // flicker fix 

[self.webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Add this to delegate after loading

```
// flicker fix

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView  
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30];

    self.webview.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution. the one where you set the background color of the web view to clear didn't work for me.

Comment: I wonder why iOS 8 continues to present this bug. Hello Apple, I am looking at you!

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered the same problem , the solution I found is as follows.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [_webView setOpaque:NO];
  _webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.webView.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

 //...........................

 self.webView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: This solution also works on macOS, when you omit the setOpaque and backgroundColor part.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding in webView settings:

```
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```