# Xamarin iOS Webview flashes white on page load

Tags: ios, flash, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin, and am trying to build an iOS WebView app.

It's fairly straightforward to get the basics working, but I'm having issues with one thing in particular. I'm trying to get the WebView to not flash white in-between page loads. So currently, if you click a link on a page, the WebView is cleared (the screen goes white) and a few moments later the new page starts rendering.

From what I understand the WebView method SuppressesIncrementalRendering should do this, but it doesn't look like its implemented\working. Is this is true? And if so, is there any kind of work-around?

As an aside, I noticed on iOS 7 and below the Safari browser has this problem, but under iOS 8 it doesn't. Even if I make my app targeting iOS 8 it unfortunately still does have the white screen. Is there perhaps an update coming to Xamarin?

Thanks for any help available :)

Answer (score 3):

Best solution:

```
[webView setOpaque:NO];
```

webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Credits to :[How to prevent initial white flash when showing a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669809/how-to-prevent-initial-white-flash-when-showing-a-uiwebview)

Comment: Is there a solution for android?

Comment: Android solution: webView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);